# Rows to update automatically after toggle button is active

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to make the code (below) so that when the toggle button is clicked it will unhide the rows. But, there are few rows within this that should be updated according to another cell and keep certain rows hidden depending on that cell value. The code below works, but the rows dont automatically update and I need to click the toggle button to hide and then unhide the rows. Is there a way to make it dynamically linked so it updates automatically which lines to hide? Thank you

```
Dim xAddress As String
xAddress = "55:136"
If Progress.Value Then
    Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(xAddress).Hidden = False
    If Range("I24").Value = "Yes" Then
        Rows("92:102").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("103:110").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("I24").Value = "No" Then
        Rows("92:102").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("103:110").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Else
    Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(xAddress).Hidden = True
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Progress` is the toggle button on Sheet1 along with all ranges, place this in Sheet1 module

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Progress_Click()
    Dim rngI24 As Boolean

    rngI24 = Me.Range("I24").Value2 = "Yes"

    Me.Rows("55:136").Hidden = Me.Progress.Value
    Me.Rows("92:102").Hidden = Not rngI24
    Me.Rows("103:110").Hidden = rngI24
End Sub
```